# Update a data.table by reference that is stored within another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating a simple aggregates (counts) by group and then within those groups other simple aggregates (again, counts). I am achieving this with a function that creates a data.table and, within it, a data.table (stored as a list) that creates counts within finer categories.

This all works fine until I try to update the sub-level data.table by reference I get the following error:
`Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error or how to resolve it.

I've tried a number of ways to update by reference, and sometimes it seems work (but I get the warning about the shallow copying being made - and more importantly successful updating of the **item_dt** table isn't done consistently).

Here's the function and execution line

```
library(data.table)
aggregator_by_geo <- function(dt_in, geo_level){

    x <- dt_in[!is.na(noc4_code),   .(uniqueN(id), 
                                      unique(noc4_code), 

                                    list(.SD[ , .(.N), by = .(item_type, items)])), 
          by = c(geo_level, 'noc4_code')][order(-V1)]

  setnames(x, c('V1', "V2", "V3"), c('N_jobs', 'noc4_code', 'item_dt'))

#' this attempt at updating by reference fails, but the function works fine otherwise:
  x[, item_dt[[1]][, 'skill_freq' := item_dt[[1]][order(-N),N]] / N_jobs, by = c(geo_level, 'noc4_code')]

  return(x)  
}

dt_agg <- aggregator_by_geo(dt, 'province') #' works if x[,item_dt[[... line is removed.
```

Example data:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(7951759L, 7976190L, 8048129L, 7969373L, 
                        8070402L, 7978834L, 8069533L, 8014283L, 7967372L, 8086152L, 8121835L, 
                        8003731L, 7993664L, 7985355L, 7987286L), 
                 province = c("ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON"), 
                 noc4_code = c("1215", '1215', "5226","6316", "1215", "6316", "1215", "6316", "6316", "5226", '6316', 
                               "5226", '6316', "1215", "6541"), 
                 items = c("Microsoft Word", "Fast-paced Setting",
                          "Online Advertising", "Leadership", "Teamwork", "Self-starter / Self-motivated", 
                          "English language", "Scheduling", "Scheduling", NA, "Time Management", 
                          "Teamwork", "Communication skills", "Generally Accepted Accounting Principles (GAAP)", 
                          "Work under pressure"), 
                 item_type = c("Tools and technology",
                          "Other", "Other", "Skills", "Other", "Other", "Knowledge", "Skills",
                          "Skills", NA, "Skills", "Other", "Skills", "Knowledge", "Other"))
```

Comment: Sorry about that - I've updated with a complete `dput` and simplified it it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to move the closing square brackets to the back, i.e.

```
x[, item_dt[[1]][, 'skill_freq' := item_dt[[1]][order(-N),N] / N_jobs], by = c(geo_level, 'noc')]
```

However, you will encounter a lot of problems with updating the list of data.tables when you keep a list of data.tables within a data.table. A sample warning below:

> In `[.data.table`(item_dt[[1L]], , `:=`("skill_freq",  ... :
>     Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can keep your data in a long format as follows:

```
aggregator_by_geo <- function(dt_in, geo_level){

    x <- dt_in[!is.na(noc4_code),  
        c(.(N_jobs=uniqueN(id), 
            noc1_code=unique(noc1_code),
            noc4_code=unique(noc4_code)), 
            .SD[ , .N, .(item_type, items)]), 
        c(geo_level, 'noc')]

    x[, skill_freq := N[order(-N)] / N_jobs, c(geo_level, 'noc')]
}
```

Since the dataset provided is not complete nor is a desired result provided nor is the actual calculation detailed, I am unable to check if my understanding of the requirements is correct.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but indeed I get the warning about the `invalid .internal.selfref`. I had included the extra `]` bracket thinking the `skill_freq` column I was adding was within the `item_dt[[1]]` table. Not exactly clear to me why it works without the closing `]`. But more importantly, is the lesson here to *avoid storing data.tables within data.tables* whenever possible?